# How to search a pattern and extract using substr in awk

Tags: awk, sed

Trying to extract a pattern using awk substr but I don't know how to remove newline. I try to get the overcloud-Controller-x

```
| driver_info            | {u'ipmi_password': u'******', u'ipmi_address': 
u'10.x.x.x', u'deploy_ramdisk': u'de76fe92-8b1f-409b-ab9c-f50232c44f0b', 
u'deploy_kernel': u'cb9c373e-c733-423a-a7a3-6a19b65b7d32', 
u'ipmi_username': u'xxx'}                                                                                                                     
|
| instance_info          | {u'root_gb': u'40', u'display_name': 
u'overcloud-Controller-1', u'image_source': u'ea293064-cbbc-4635-9d5f- 
50b91c8b20c0', u'capabilities': u'{"profile": "Controller", "boot_option": 
"local"}', u'memory_mb': u'6144', u'vcpus': u'4', u'local_gb': u'837', 
u'configdrive': u'******', u'swap_mb': u'0'}                              |
| name                   | server-1


| driver_info            | {u'ipmi_password': u'******', u'ipmi_address': 
u'10.x.x.y', u'deploy_ramdisk': u'de76fe92-8b1f-409b-ab9c-f50232c44f0b', 
u'deploy_kernel': u'cb9c373e-c733-423a-a7a3-6a19b65b7d32', 
u'ipmi_username': u'xxx'}                                                                                                                       
|
| instance_info          | {u'root_gb': u'40', u'display_name': 
u'overcloud-Controller-2', u'image_source': u'ea293064-cbbc-4635-9d5f- 
50b91c8b20c0', u'capabilities': u'{"profile": "Controller", "boot_option": 
"local"}', u'memory_mb': u'6144', u'vcpus': u'4', u'local_gb': u'837', 
u'configdrive': u'******', u'swap_mb': u'0'}                              |
| name                   | server-2
```

when I run the follow awk script, there are always newline.

```
awk '{match($0,/display_name/); nodename=substr($0,RSTART+17, RLENGTH+10); gsub(/   /, "",nodename);printf "(%s)\n",nodename}' alex-test.txt
```

Output:

```
(overcloud-Controller-1)
()
()
()
(overcloud-Controller-2)
()
()
```

Please advise how to remove newline? i am using tr -d '\n' at the end but it removed all newline so it becomes one line.

```
(overcloud-Controller-1)()()()(overcloud-Controller-2)()()
```

Expected output:

```
(overcloud-Controller-1)
(overcloud-Controller-2)
```

why I printed extra newline? any advise? it seems printf printed also newline. if I print only the variable nodename, then it will resolve my question also.

my real data is only 3 lines and then parser for server-2

```
| driver_info            | {u'ipmi_password'
| instance_info          | {u'root_gb': u'40
| name                   | server-1
```

Update script and started working based on the idea of @RavainderSing13. I just added RS and FS in front of awk, that is it. Thanks.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="[|\n]" '{match($0,/display_name/); 
nodename=substr($0,RSTART+17, RLENGTH+10); gsub(/   /, "",nodename);;printf 
"(%s)\n",nodename}' ava-ipmi.txt

(overcloud-Controller-2)
(overcloud-Controller-0)
(overcloud-Controller-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="[|\n]" -v s1="'" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i ~ /display_name/){
         split($(i+1),array,"[,]")
         sub(/^u/,"",array[1])
         gsub(s1,"",array[1])
         print "("array[1]")"
     }
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
(overcloud-Controller-1)
(overcloud-Controller-2)
```

IMHO, why OP's code is printing extra NULL values too since OP is not checking condition either string display is present in any match or not, so eve it is NOT present it is printing, the is possible reason of it is printing `()` in output.

Comment: it printed only () like you said

Comment: @AndrewS, my code is working fine for me  for given samples. can you also check once `cat -v Input_file` and see if there are Control M characters and let me know then?

Comment: I think I know why.  i updated on main question. 3 lines per parse. i copied data from here and run, it works like you said. my real data is diff (3 lines per block)

Comment: @AndrewS, so is it not working for your real data? Sorry I am not getting how shown sample and your real samples are different?

Comment: RavainderSing13, you gave me an idea. my way is also working. But I believed your  method is also working.  data copied to this page is not formated correctly.  I will update my main page. but I will accept your answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Update script and started working based on the idea of @RavainderSing13. I just added RS and FS in front of awk, that is it. Thanks.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="[|\n]" '{match($0,/display_name/); 
nodename=substr($0,RSTART+17, RLENGTH+10); gsub(/   /, "",nodename);printf 
"(%s)\n",nodename}' ava-ipmi.txt

(overcloud-Controller-2)
(overcloud-Controller-0)
(overcloud-Controller-1)
```

Comment: Thank you to you and everyone here!

Comment: You're not using fields at all so setting `FS` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F\' '{print "("$34")"}' file
(overcloud-Controller-1)
(overcloud-Controller-2)
```